# Class not found in file after changing the name

Tags: php, composer-php

I changed the name of every function in this repo: https://github.com/twisted1919/mailwizz-php-sdk

from `MailWizzApi_...` to `MyNameApi_...` via Sublime. Now once I run the code it tells me that it can not find the variable MyNameApi_Config in file /examples/setup.php although it is there.

I have already tried running composer update/clean dump etc. what I have found.

Has anybody any Idea on this?

EDIT:

I've changed all classes and names that were named `MailWizzApi` to `MyNameApi` including all files via substitute function. That should do the job ... at least normally.

Comment: What did you change give a list. Also, did you change all the class names too? I wonder why would you do that.

Comment: Did you updated autoloader used by this library? https://github.com/twisted1919/mailwizz-php-sdk/blob/master/MailWizzApi/Autoloader.php#L40

Comment: I tried 'composer update' ... is this what you mean?

Comment: No, @rob006 linked to a certain line the source code that needs to be adapted too.

Comment: I have updated that line in the autoloader ... yes but still no luck @rob006